# CSS & HTML in Design

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if anyone has come across how to create an arrow in CSS (Yes I want to know in CSS) - Any website / tutorials in CSS design would be highly appreciate.

Something like this:

[image]

Anyone can suggest me how to do this?

Edited: Sorry I mean a chevron!!

Comment: Yes they have. You're welcome.

Comment: I wouldn't bother. Use a PNG or SVG. If you really want to, use a CSS triangle and a rectangle together, but there isn't really any reason too.

Comment: http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/?utm_source=CSS-Weekly&utm_campaign=Issue-48&utm_medium=email

Comment: @marcelo2605 thanks for the link but that isn't exactly the same as I want, but close though thanks. Rich Bradshaw, I know it probably much hassle but I like to know.

Comment: I've answered @benito

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

Ha, you asked for an arrow, but actually wanted a chevron!

For the shape you want, why not just use a massive `<`?

If that's not OK, just overlay two triangles, one red, one white…

http://cdpn.io/LykHa

```
.chevron {
  position:relative;
}
.chevron::before {
  position:absolute;
  left:10px;
  top:0;
  content:'';
  display:block;
  border-color:transparent transparent transparent red;
  border-width:20px;
  border-style:solid;
}
.chevron::after {
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0;
  content:'';
  display:block;
  border-color:transparent transparent transparent white;
  border-width:20px;
  border-style:solid;
}
```

---

For fun – http://cdpn.io/yaqGs

I wouldn't really do it like this though – I'd likely use a PNG or an SVG. Looks like my rectangle is out by a pixel, so the number might need tweaking a little.

Looks like:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class='arrow'></div>
```

CSS:

There's a triangle after, and a rectangle before.

```
.arrow {
  position:relative;
}
.arrow::after {
  position:absolute;
  left:40px;
  top:0;
  content:'';
  display:block;
  border-color:transparent transparent transparent red;
  border-width:20px;
  border-style:solid;
}

.arrow::before {
  position:absolute;
  top:14px;
  content:'';
  display:block;
  height:10px;
  width:40px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: yes thanks a lot I can just see the gray line overlap the red. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Either use

```
.foo:before { content: "‹"; }
```

Or make a triangle like described [here](http://cssshapes.iweb.uz/).

BTW: The downvotes for your answer are justfied. Feel bad for it.